# Mysql query to copy timestamp data from another

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, timestamp, mysql-workbench

I was working on mysql query and could not get it running. I am trying to copy timestamp field data from one table to another based on user id. It is not straight forward. Here is the story. In the score table I have User_id, question id Tag id and add_date field......   There are various Tag id for one user in that table and I want to copy add date field  for each user where tagid=627 in the other table called as User in its respective Date_record(timestap) field which is 0000 0000 right now .Once again, trying to Copy add_date field for each user where tagid=627(for each) and paste to the same user id(field name is id for this table which is same a suser id) in other table in the Date_record field which is time stamp and currently 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  For example, screen shot of tables.

http://minus.com/lw2prl55nTBHA
user table with empty Date_record field(timestamp) which will be having data from score table(next) for same user id(int this table id is same as user_id) and tag id=627][1]

http://minus.com/lby84cURuoD5DN
score table in which for same user id there are diff tag id and I want to copy tagid =627 add_date data field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update `user` 
join score on `user`.User_id = score.User_id
set `user`.Date_record = score.Date_record
where score.tagid = 627
```

Comment: thanks, just wondering as user table dont have user_id field, infact it is Id which is same as userid and there is no date_record field in score table, it is add_date, so I am assuming, query wil be then: update `user` 
join score on `user`.id = score.User_id
set `user`.Date_record = score.add_date
where score.tagid = 627

Comment: I guess that worked but what if there are some entries in daterecord field and I dont want to over write it?

Comment: @user1706989 Only fields specified in set ... will be over-written.